# How to do this in Dplyr?

Tags: dplyr

I have this df for example:

[image]

And I wish to obtain the following df

[image]

How is this possible?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to create a one-row dataframe from the colors in each group, and expand it:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  tibble(digits = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5)) %>% 
  mutate(letters = LETTERS[digits],
         fruits = c("apple", "orange", "grapes", "ananas", "pineapple")[digits],
         colors = c("red", "green", "green", "purple", "green", "yellow", "yellow"))

df %>% 
  group_by(digits, letters, fruits) %>% 
  summarise(colors = list(as.data.frame(matrix(colors, nrow = 1))), 
            .groups = "drop") %>% 
  unnest(colors)
```